# How to get correct page-number from stackoverflow?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have a problem in finding correct page number from stackoverflow.
During I am making python web-scraper code, I try to get page number from this web. But the last number is not correct.
I checked my code and there isn't any problem in my code. others numbers are correct.
It is problem of the stackoverflow web site? or I missed something?

Here is my code:

```
url = ("https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?q=python")


so_info = requests.get(url)
so_soup = BeautifulSoup(so_info.text, "html.parser")
pagination = so_soup.find("div", {"class": "s-pagination"})
pages = pagination.find_all("a")
a = []
for page in pages[:-1]:
    number = page.find("span")
    a.append(number.get_text())
print(a)
```

And the result of this code is: **['1', '2', '3', '4', '83']**
In this result, it has to be 24, instead of 83.
Thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCfVS.png)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Jobs from stack overflow]

You are **scraping** the HTML , why should the result be 24 instead of 83?

[image: HTML]

I think the result you are getting is the expected, if not, let me know why

Comment: I don't know why but in my case, last page is 24, and also into the anchor, title="page x of 24"
I am gonna search if there are some peoples that have same problem. 
Thanks for reply